why my django save_model not saving manytomany relation
I'm having issues with ManytoMany Relationships that are not saving in a model when I save it (via the admin).
i want to auto add title in tags.
admin.py
def save_model(self, request: Any, obj: Any, form: Any, change: Any) -> None:
    post = Fa.objects.get(id = obj.id) #return the current post fields
    for i in post.title.split(' '):
        try:
            t = FaTag.objects.get(title = i)
            post.tag.add(t)                
        except:
            pass               
    return super(FaAdmin,self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

when i print this line:
obj.tag.all()

it gives me the queryset that is currect but it wont save anything in database

It does, and next it does the save_m2m of the modeladmin, which will clear the m2m again, and then save the m2m.

@willeM_VanOnsem thanks. how can i prevent save_m2m and save my m2m relation?
